# How can I update column adminID?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I try to create user registration with roles. And now I have 2 tables User, Admin. in table Users I want to save adminId.

My models is:

```
const User = sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    mail: {type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true},
    password: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    adminId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true},
    img: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true}
})

const Admin = sequelize.define('admins', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
}) 

Admin.belongsTo(User,{foreignKey: 'userId'});
```

My controllers is:

```
class UserController {
    async create(req, res, next){
        const {mail, password} = req.body
        if (!mail || !password || !name || !telegram) {
            return next(ApiError.badRequest('Некорректный ввод данных'))
        }
        const candidate = await User.findOne({where: {mail}})
        if (candidate) {
            return next(ApiError.badRequest('Пользователь с таким email уже существует'))
        }
        const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 5)
        const user = await User.create({mail, password: hashPassword})
        if(role === "Admin"){
          const admin = await AdminController.create()
        }
 
        const token = generateJwt(user.id, user.mail, user.role)
        return res.json({token})
    }
class AdminController {
    async create(req, res, next){
        const admin = await Admin.create()
        const user = User.update(
            { adminId: admin.id},
            { where: { userId: admin.createdAt } }
          )
      }
```

After creating user, how can I send and response userId in AdminController. And add Admin's id from table Admin to adminId in table Users.

Comment: You shouldn't use one controller in another one. Extract all DB operations into services and use them in controllers. Such an approach is called "Onion architecture". Please read about it and try to build separate layers in your app.

Comment: thanks a lot @Anatoly